# Detach single record from pivot table LARAVEL

Tags: php, laravel, many-to-many, detach

I have two models, `Menu` and `User` with `many to many relationship`. So, at this moment I have lot of records with the same `user_id` and `menu_id` in the pivot table, and the user must to can detach only one of them and not all of them.

So, I made a AJAX request to "remove" one menu from this table:

```
function deleteMenuFromOrder(menuFromOrderId){
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/removeMenuFromOrder",
        data: {
            menuFromOrderId : menuFromOrderId,
            userId : "{{$user->id}}",
            _token : "{{csrf_token()}}"
        },
        success: function (response) {
            alert(response);
            // location.reload();
        },
        fail: function(response){
            alert(response);
        }
    });
}
```

And this the "controller":

```
Route::get('/removeMenuFromOrder', function (HttpRequest $request) {
    $user = User::findOrFail($request['userId']);
    $user->menus()->detach($request['menuFromOrderId']);
    return "Menú eliminado con éxito";
});
```

The `menuFromOrderId` is the `id` from pivot table which I want to delete.

Unfortunately, I can't to upload images on StackOverflow yet, but I have linked one about pivot table's data.

https://ibb.co/KqR7Cdj

How you can see, I have lot of records with the same user_id and menu_id, if i detach by user_id, all records will be deleted and viceverse.

So, how can I detach only single record in this case?

Comment: Pivot tables in Laravel generally don't have an `id` column, and because of this, if you use that `id` in detach, it will not work. You need to reference the `menu_id` column, like `$user->menus()->detach({pivot_table_menu_id})` (obviously replacing `{pivot_table_menu_id}` with a valid integer)

Comment: I don't see a question here. What problems are you having?

Comment: After re-reading your question, if you're attaching the same menu to the same user multiple times (why?), you're going to run into issues with that. You can do `DB::table('pivot_table')->where('id', $request['menuFromOrderId'])->delete()` instead, but I think you need to rethink what's happening here.

Comment: Im going to actualize my question, I hope explain myself better

Comment: Ok @TimLewis, I think that can be useful! Im going to try. If I want to attach same menu to same user is becasue I'm simulating a bought like UberEats when you can buy two same menus, i don't know if i explain correctly

Comment: Yes, yours answer worked correctly @TimLewis! Thank you so much

Comment: Right, that makes sense yeah, but I would expect that to be tied to an Order, not to a User. i.e. a User "Orders" "Example Menu" today, then again tomorrow; those are two separate orders, 1 and 2, so Menu 1 (Example Menu) would be tied to those. And awesome! Glad to hear that helps 

Comment: Yes, there are also another Order table, but this table only save current order, like shopping cart, when you confirm your bought, then this data goes to order table

Comment: I don't think I quite understand, but ultimately I think *you* understand what's going on and why, so take that information away, and if you can get it to work with your current project, that's awesome  If not, reference this question again; see if there's something you can adjust and learn from the experience. Cheers!

Comment: Perfect @TimLewis! I take note about you! It's a fact i need to learn more about database architecture but I found with some problem, I'll call you hahaha thank u so much!!